# The dollar ($) prefixed field '$addToSet' in '$addToSet' is not valid for storage

Tags: mongodb

I’ve been trying to use $addToSet in a findAndModify query using the node.js api. But I’m receiving an error that the prefixed field $addToSet is not valid for storage. The query works using the mongo shell client, but just not with the api.

```
MongoClient.connect(config.mongo.uri, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err)
    console.log('Connected to mongodb');
    db.collection(‘users’).findAndModify(
         {‘username’: ‘foo’}, 
         [], 
         {$addToSet: {roles: “somerole”}}, 
         {upsert: true, new: true}, function(err, user) {
         if (err) console.log(err});
    });
```

The above code gives me an error complaining about setting a field that begins with the protected keyword $addToSet this error:

> MongoError: exception: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$addToSet' in '$addToSet' is not valid for storage.

Versions:
mongod: 2.6.6
node mongodb: 1.4.31

Comment: This worked fine when I tried it, but I did need to change the smart-quotes to normal quotes.  Not sure if that's just a copy and paste problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the changes in 2.6 I rewrote the code to use find/update.

```
MongoClient.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err)
    console.log('Connected to mongodb');

    db.collection('users').find({'username': username}, function(err, user) {
        var user_data = {'username': username}
        if (user) {
            user_data['$addToSet'] = { roles: item['RolesRoleName']};
            db.collection('users').update({_id: user._id}, user_data, function(err, user) {
                if (err) console.log(username, err);
                console.log("Updated", username);
            });
        } else {
            user_data['roles'] = [item.IsSuperUser == "TRUE" ? "admin" : "user"];
            db.collection('users').save(user_data, function(err, user) {
                if (err) console.log(username, err);
                console.log("Added", username)
        });
    });
});
```